# How to use rootless Docker as remote host?

Tags: ssh, docker

I'd like to run a Docker container on a server by running the `docker` command on my computer. I install
`Ubuntu 18.04.3 (LTS) x64` on my server, create a new non-root user

```sh
root@server:~#  useradd --create-home --shell /bin/bash unpriv
```

configure SSH and connect to the server as non-root user

```sh
me@local:~#  ssh unpriv@SERVER_IP
```

to [install rootless Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/) by running

```sh
unpriv@server:~#  curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/rootless | sh
```

As the output of the script tells me, I add

```sh
export PATH=/home/unpriv/bin:$PATH
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock
```

to `/home/unpriv/.bashrc`, which I then re-source

```sh
unpriv@server:~#  source .bashrc
```

Then I start the Docker service

```
unpriv@server:~#  systemctl --user start docker
```

Now I can run a Docker container from my SSH session

```
unpriv@server:~#  docker run --rm hello-world
```

However, if I set

```
me@local:~#  export DOCKER_HOST=ssh://unpriv@SERVER_IP
```

on my computer and try to run the container, I get an error

```
me@local:~#  docker run --rm hello-world
docker: error during connect: Post http://docker/v1.40/containers/create: command [ssh -l unpriv 161.35.202.145 -- docker system dial-stdio] has exited with exit status 127, please make sure the URL is valid, and Docker 18.09 or later is installed on the remote host: stderr=bash: docker: command not found
.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I assume that the added environment variables `PATH` and `DOCKER_HOST` that I added to `home/unpriv/.bashrc` on the server are not considered. Hence, the `docker` command is not found (on the server). What am I missing in my configuration?

Comment: Did you add those variables to the beginning or end of the `.bashrc`? There's typically a line to stop parsing the file for non-interactive shells.

Comment: @BMitch You are right. Adding the environment variables at the beginning works. I added them at the end :facepalm:

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @BMitch. I added the environment variables at the end, but should have added them at the beginning of `/home/unpriv/.bashrc`, e.g. before

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

Comment: Just checking in, this is still the solution as of the posting of this comment. Just be aware your distro's check for non-interactive mode might look a little different. On Debian 11, it was a case statement.

Comment: Worked for me too. Add DOCKER_HOST=xxx at the top of your .bashrc.

The Debian case statement alluded to:
```bash
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```